# C++ convert hex string to signed integer

Tags: c++, integer, hex, signed

I want to convert a hex string to a 32 bit signed integer in C++.

So, for example, I have the hex string "fffefffe".  The binary representation of this is 11111111111111101111111111111110.  The signed integer representation of this is: -65538.

How do I do this conversion in C++?  This also needs to work for non-negative numbers.  For example, the hex string "0000000A", which is 00000000000000000000000000001010 in binary, and 10 in decimal.

Comment: Note. You will only get -65538 for systems where sizeof(int) == 4

Comment: @Martin York, He didn't mention `int`. "32 bit signed integer" could be int32_t or __int32 etc.

Comment: Related, see [Convert hexadecimal string with leading “0x” to signed short in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1487440/608639)

Answer (score 276, accepted):

use `std::stringstream`

```
unsigned int x;   
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << "fffefffe";
ss >> x;
```

the following example produces `-65538` as its result:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned int x;   
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << "fffefffe";
    ss >> x;
    // output it as a signed type
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << std::endl;
}
```

In the new C++11 standard, there are a few new utility functions which you can make use of! specifically, there is a family of "string to number" functions (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul). These are essentially thin wrappers around C's string to number conversion functions, but know how to deal with a `std::string`

So, the simplest answer for newer code would probably look like this:

```
std::string s = "0xfffefffe";
unsigned int x = std::stoul(s, nullptr, 16);
```

---

**NOTE:** Below is my original answer, which as the edit says is not a complete answer. For a functional solution, stick the code above the line :-).

It appears that since `lexical_cast<>` is defined to have stream conversion semantics. Sadly, streams don't understand the "0x" notation. So both the `boost::lexical_cast` and my hand rolled one don't deal well with hex strings. The above solution which manually sets the input stream to hex will handle it just fine.

[Boost has some stuff](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) to do this as well, which has some nice error checking capabilities as well. You can use it like this:

```
try {
    unsigned int x = lexical_cast<int>("0x0badc0de");
} catch(bad_lexical_cast &) {
    // whatever you want to do...
}
```

If you don't feel like using boost, here's a light version of lexical cast which does no error checking:

```
template<typename T2, typename T1>
inline T2 lexical_cast(const T1 &in) {
    T2 out;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << in;
    ss >> out;
    return out;
}
```

which you can use like this:

```
// though this needs the 0x prefix so it knows it is hex
unsigned int x = lexical_cast<unsigned int>("0xdeadbeef");
```

Comment: When I use that method, I end up with an integer value of 152144602

Comment: @jmanning2k, yea, it's weird that both boost and my lexical_cast barf on hex strings (even with the 0x prefix) if i don't put std::hex in the string.

Comment: For the stringstream example, wouldn't it be appropriate to check the streams failbit and/or badbit?

Comment: @SteveWilkinson: Read the paragraph starting with the "**EDIT**". It explains how you need to use `std::hex`

Comment: For `stringstream`s one should check `ss.good() && ss.eof()` to make sure no errors occurred.

Comment: @EvanTeran This question is a bit old, but hopefully you are still around to help me resolve a doubt. If `0xfffefffe` corresponds to a signed integer value, why is your variable `x` an `unsigned int`? Similarly, why do you have to use `stoul` instead of `stoi` to make this work? I tried `stoi` and it throws an exception. Thanks you any help you may give me!

Comment: Note that the `stoi` family of function will accept strings like `1random2character3` (parsed as 1), and it's up to you as the caller to check the data written to the second argument

Comment: this "stoul" save my logic

Comment: @atoMerz I think it should be `ss.eof() && !ss.fail()`, `good()` is false when eof was reached, while fail() is true when conversion failed.

Answer (score 72):

For a method that works with both C and C++, you might want to consider using the standard library function strtol().

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "abcd";
    char * p;
    long n = strtol( s.c_str(), & p, 16 );
    if ( * p != 0 ) { //my bad edit was here
        cout << "not a number" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `strtoul` not `strtol`. There will be `+ overflow` when using strtol. With `strtoul` there will be no overflow and returned value will be converted to `long` to produce correct result (-65538). So your answer almost right :)

Comment: +1. Because strtol (or strtoul) faster than using stringstream.

Answer (score 27):

Andy Buchanan, as far as sticking to C++ goes, I liked yours, but I have a few mods:

```
template <typename ElemT>
struct HexTo {
    ElemT value;
    operator ElemT() const {return value;}
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, HexTo& out) {
        in >> std::hex >> out.value;
        return in;
    }
};
```

Used like

```
uint32_t value = boost::lexical_cast<HexTo<uint32_t> >("0x2a");
```

That way you don't need one impl per int type.

Comment: I would have taken that step too, but I find that I like to limit the proliferation of angle brackets. For this case I felt breaking the "don't duplicate code" rule was justified. :-)

Comment: Unfortunate that it's necessary, but nicely done.  Added to my personal STL/Boost extensions/fixes header.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this only works for unsigned conversion. So you can not convert 0xFFFFFFFF to -1.

Comment: @fmuecke: That's because 0xFFFFFFFF is a signed integer overflow, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 16):

Working example with `strtoul` will be:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
    string s = "fffefffe";
    char * p;
    long n = strtoul( s.c_str(), & p, 16 ); 
    if ( * p != 0 ) {  
        cout << "not a number" << endl;
    }    else {  
        cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

`strtol` converts `string` to `long`. On my computer `numeric_limits<long>::max()` gives `0x7fffffff`. Obviously that `0xfffefffe` is greater than `0x7fffffff`. So `strtol` returns `MAX_LONG` instead of wanted value. `strtoul` converts `string` to `unsigned long` that's why no overflow in this case.

Ok, `strtol` is considering input string not as 32-bit signed integer before convertation. Funny sample with `strtol`:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
    string s = "-0x10002";
    char * p;
    long n = strtol( s.c_str(), & p, 16 ); 
    if ( * p != 0 ) {  
        cout << "not a number" << endl;
    }    else {  
        cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

The code above prints `-65538` in console.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simple and working method I found elsewhere:

```
string hexString = "7FF";
int hexNumber;
sscanf(hexString.c_str(), "%x", &hexNumber);
```

Please note that you might prefer using unsigned long integer/long integer, to receive the value.
Another note, the c_str() function just converts the std::string to const char* .

So if you have a const char* ready, just go ahead with using that variable name directly, as shown below [I am also showing the usage of the unsigned long variable for a larger hex number. Do not confuse it with the case of having const char* instead of string]:

```
const char *hexString = "7FFEA5"; //Just to show the conversion of a bigger hex number
unsigned long hexNumber; //In case your hex number is going to be sufficiently big.
sscanf(hexString, "%x", &hexNumber);
```

This works just perfectly fine (provided you use appropriate data types per your need).

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem today, here's how I solved it so I could keep lexical_cast<>

```
typedef unsigned int    uint32;
typedef signed int      int32;

class uint32_from_hex   // For use with boost::lexical_cast
{
    uint32 value;
public:
    operator uint32() const { return value; }
    friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& in, uint32_from_hex& outValue )
    {
        in >> std::hex >> outValue.value;
    }
};

class int32_from_hex   // For use with boost::lexical_cast
{
    uint32 value;
public:
    operator int32() const { return static_cast<int32>( value ); }
    friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& in, int32_from_hex& outValue )
    {
        in >> std::hex >> outvalue.value;
    }
};

uint32 material0 = lexical_cast<uint32_from_hex>( "0x4ad" );
uint32 material1 = lexical_cast<uint32_from_hex>( "4ad" );
uint32 material2 = lexical_cast<uint32>( "1197" );

int32 materialX = lexical_cast<int32_from_hex>( "0xfffefffe" );
int32 materialY = lexical_cast<int32_from_hex>( "fffefffe" );
// etc...
```

(Found this page when I was looking for a less sucky way :-)

Cheers,
A.

Comment: Code has trivial compilation error - outvalue is not defined (should be outValue).

Answer (score 5):

just use stoi/stol/stoll
for example:

```
std::cout << std::stol("fffefffe", nullptr, 16) << std::endl;
```

output: 4294901758

Comment: Just edit `stol` to `stoi`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
string string_test = "80123456";
unsigned long x;
signed long val;

std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::hex << string_test;
ss >> x;
// ss >> val;  // if I try this val = 0
val = (signed long)x;  // However, if I cast the unsigned result I get val = 0x80123456
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this. This solution is a bit risky. There are no checks. The string must only have hex values and the string length must match the return type size. But no need for extra headers.

```
char hextob(char ch)
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') return ch - '0';
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F') return ch - 'A' + 10;
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f') return ch - 'a' + 10;
    return 0;
}
template<typename T>
T hextot(char* hex)
{
    T value = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T)*2; ++i)
        value |= hextob(hex[i]) << (8*sizeof(T)-4*(i+1));
    return value;
};
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    char str[4] = {'f','f','f','f'};
    std::cout << hextot<int16_t>(str)  << "\n";
}
```

Note: the length of the string must be divisible by 2

Comment: `std::hex` and `std::stoul()` and `sscanf()` are permissive, so if I pass a wrong "FK" it would result in 15 (ignores K and considers F). at hextob I changed the return to `std::cerr<<"ERROR: invalid ch='"<<ch<<"'"<<"\n";exit(1);`, this way I can grant the input was perfect, but I am using this instead, for just at most 0xFF `int hexaTo(const char* pch) {return hextob(pch[0])*16+hextob(pch[1]);}`

Answer (score 1):

For those looking to convert number base for unsigned numbers, it is pretty trivial to do yourself in both C/C++ with minimal dependency (only operator not provided by the language itself is `pow()` function).

In mathematical terms, a positive ordinal number *d* in base *b* with *n* number of digits can be converted to base 10 using:

[image: math summation]

Example: Converting base 16 number `00f` looks like:

[image: math summation] = 0*16^2 + 0*16^1 + 16*16^0 = 15

C/C++ Example:

```
#include <math.h>

unsigned int to_base10(char *d_str, int len, int base)
{
    if (len < 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    char d = d_str[0];
    // chars 0-9 = 48-57, chars a-f = 97-102
    int val = (d > 57) ? d - ('a' - 10) : d - '0';
    int result = val * pow(base, (len - 1));
    d_str++; // increment pointer
    return result + to_base10(d_str, len - 1, base);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char n[] = "00f"; // base 16 number of len = 3
    printf("%d\n", to_base10(n, 3, 16));
}
```

Comment: `to_base10` function accepts any string ( char * ) without checking if the provided string is hex or not