# Convert hexadecimal string with leading "0x" to signed short in C++?

Tags: c++, string, hex, int, short

I found the code to convert a hexadecimal string into a `signed int` using `strtol`, but I can't find something for a short int (2 bytes). Here' my piece of code :

```
while (!sCurrentFile.eof() )
{
    getline (sCurrentFile,currentString);
    sOutputFile<<strtol(currentString.c_str(),NULL,16)<<endl;
}
```

My idea is to read a file with 2 bytes wide values (like 0xFFEE), convert it to signed int and write the result in an output file. Execution speed is not an issue.

I could find some ways to avoid the problem, but I'd like to use a "one line" solution, so maybe you can help for this :)

Edit : The files look like this :

```
0x0400
0x03fe
0x03fe
...
```

Edit : I already tried with the hex operator, but I still have to convert the string to an integer before doing so.

```
// This won't work as currentString is not an integer
myInt << std::hex << currentString.c_str();
```

Comment: What does your input file look like? It is pretty hard to make any recommendations without this information.

Comment: please see strtol returns long , not signed int,

Comment: sscanf returns an int, but the return value of scanf-family functions is the number of fields they successfully converted. While I appreciate the publicity, you transcribed it wrong. :)

Comment: edit : my bad, I wanted to reduce the code and didnt't look to what I was doing - it was the end of my work day :)

Comment: It looks like Loki is the only person to actually answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered `sscanf` with the "%hx" conversion qualifier?

Comment: Or, if you don't have any particular need to use C++ I/O streams, go straight to fscanf... Depends on how much of that code you control.

Comment: fscanf and sscanf are how I usually handle this. I have a program right now that reads CRC hex strings similar to this: 

sscanf(cstr_fileCRC, "%lX", &ul_fileCRC);

Comment: The question is tagged C++. Plus, `sscanf` is usually frowned upon because of the security related problems it carries with it.

Answer (score 5):

This should be simple:

```
std::ifstream   file("DataFile");
int             value;

while(file >> std::hex >> value)  // Reads a hex string and converts it to an int.
{
    std::cout << "Value: " << std::hex << value << "\n";
}
```

While we are talking about files:
You should **NOT** do this:

```
while (!sCurrentFile.eof() )
{
    getline (sCurrentFile,currentString);
    ... STUFF ...
}
```

This is because when you read the last line it does **NOT** set the EOF. So when you loop around and then read the line after the last line, getline() will fail and you will be doing STUFF on what was in currentString from the last time it was set up. So in-effect you will processes the last line twice.

The correct way to loop over a file is:

```
while (getline(sCurrentFile,currentString))
{
    // If the get fails then you have read past EOF and loop is not entered.
    ... STUFF ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can probably use [stringtream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) class's >> operator with hex manipulator.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, it's just one line big !

Comment: You should probably provide an example. The leading `0x` appears to cause the parsing to fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
// convert unsigned-integer to it's hexadecimal string represention
// 0x12345678 -> '12345678'
// N is BYTE/WORD/UINT/ULONGLONG
// T is char or wchar_t
template <class N, class T> inline T* UnsignedToHexStr(N    n             ,  // [i  ]
                                                       T*   pcStr         ,  // [i/o] filled with string
                                                       UINT nDigits       ,  // [i  ] number of digits in output string / 0 (auto)
                                                       bool bNullTerminate ) // [i  ] whether to add NULL termination
{
    if ((N)-1 < (N)1)              // if type of N is floating-point / signed-integer
        if (::IsDebuggerPresent())
        {
            ::OutputDebugString(_T("UnsignedToHexStr: Incorrect type passed\n"));
            ::DebugBreak();
        }

    if (!nDigits)
        nDigits= GetUnsignedHexDigits(n);

    if (1 == sizeof(T))
    {
        const char _czIntHexConv[]= "0123456789ABCDEF";
        for (int i= nDigits-1; i>= 0; i--)
        {
            char* pLoc= (char*)&pcStr[i];
            *pLoc= _czIntHexConv[n & 0x0F];
            n >>= 4;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        const wchar_t _czIntHexConv[]= L"0123456789ABCDEF";
        for (int i= nDigits-1; i>= 0; i--)
        {
            wchar_t* pLoc= (wchar_t*)&pcStr[i];
            *pLoc= _czIntHexConv[n & 0x0F];
            n >>= 4;
        }
    }

    if (bNullTerminate)
        pcStr[nDigits]= 0;

    return pcStr;
}



// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// convert unsigned-integer in HEX string represention to it's numerical value
// '1234' -> 0x1234
// N is BYTE/WORD/UINT/ULONGLONG
// T is char or wchar_t
template <class N, class T> inline bool HexStrToUnsigned(const T* pczSrc                    ,
                                                         N&       n                         ,
                                                         bool     bSpecificTerminator= false,  // whether string should terminate with specific terminating char
                                                         T        cTerminator        = 0     ) // specific terminating char
{
    n= 0;

    if (!pczSrc)
        return false;

    while ((32 == *pczSrc) || (9 == *pczSrc))
        pczSrc++;

    bool bLeadZeros= *pczSrc == _T('0');
    while (*pczSrc == _T('0')) // skip leading zeros
        pczSrc++;

    BYTE nMaxDigits= 2*sizeof(N);
    BYTE nDigits   = 0          ;

    while (true)
    {
        if ( (*pczSrc >= _T('0')) && (*pczSrc <= _T('9')))
        { if (nDigits==nMaxDigits) return false; n= (n<<4) + (*pczSrc-_T('0')   ); pczSrc++; nDigits++; continue; }

        if ( (*pczSrc >= _T('A')) && (*pczSrc <= _T('F')))
        { if (nDigits==nMaxDigits) return false; n= (n<<4) + (*pczSrc-_T('A')+10); pczSrc++; nDigits++; continue; }

        if ( (*pczSrc >= _T('a')) && (*pczSrc <= _T('f')))
        { if (nDigits==nMaxDigits) return false; n= (n<<4) + (*pczSrc-_T('a')+10); pczSrc++; nDigits++; continue; }

        if (bSpecificTerminator)
            if (*pczSrc != cTerminator)
                return false;

        break;
    }

    return (nDigits>0) || bLeadZeros; // at least one digit
}
```

Comment: You are obviously quite mad :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you're sure the data can be trusted from `currentString.c_str()`, then you could also easily do

```
myInt << std::hex << atoi(currentString.c_str());
```

Comment: Why use the C functions when the C++ stream aleady does all the work.

Comment: The question is tagged C++, not C.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the data is always going to be in that format, couldn't you just do something like:

```
myInt << std::hex << currentString.c_str() +2; // skip the leading "0x"
```

Comment: Here the std::hex does nothing as it processing a string. You are just re-printing the string you read (minus the first two characters).