# How to convert a string of hex values to a string?

Tags: c++, string, stl, ascii

Say I have a string like:

```
string hex = "48656c6c6f";
```

Where every two characters correspond to the hex representation of their ASCII, value, eg:

```
0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f = "Hello"
```

So how can I get `"hello"` from `"48656c6c6f"` without having to create a lookup ASCII table? `atoi()` obviously won't work here.

Comment: Related, see [Convert hexadecimal string with leading “0x” to signed short in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1487440/608639)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
int len = hex.length();
std::string newString;
for(int i=0; i< len; i+=2)
{
    std::string byte = hex.substr(i,2);
    char chr = (char) (int)strtol(byte.c_str(), null, 16);
    newString.push_back(chr);
}
```

Comment: I'd go with this answer, as it wont depend on integer lengths

Comment: Storing a length in an `int`. Now why would you do that?

Comment: @sbi: If I didn't, it would call string::length() every time through the loop.  Since I know it's going to remain constant, no need going through the extra work.  (Unless you are questioning my choice of int over say long -- because I couldn't see this as being practical on a string longer than that which would fit into an int length)

Comment: @James Is `string::length()` O(1)?

Comment: @James: The length of a `std::string` is to be stored in `std::string::size_type`. The C lib uses `std::size_t` for this.

Comment: @NullUSerException: I'm not sure if that's a requirement or not, but regardless, O(1) is not O(0).

Comment: This is *ten times* slower than it needs to be (see my answer).

Comment: I agree with sbi: use size_t for this. Your IDE/compiler should flag this as a warning anyway.

Comment: "Since I know it's going to remain constant" any serious compiler should know that, and LICM the length check out of the loop, since `hex` is only read from. Even Javascript JITs have been doing it since before this answer was posted.

Comment: @Masklinn - Actually, we call a member function on `hex`, so the compiler would have to know the `std::string::substr()` does not affect the length of the string.  In fact, it would have to know that every call to the member function `length()` returns the same value. Now, since `string` is part of the standard library, the compiler *could* know these things, but it's not guaranteed, and technically, out of its scope to make those assumptions.

Comment: `null` is undefined in gcc compiler in linux !

Comment: @Saam Sorry, I keep forgetting `null` is from C#.  `NULL` is probably defined, but if not, use `0`.

Answer (score 26):

Hex digits are very easy to convert to binary:

```
// C++98 guarantees that '0', '1', ... '9' are consecutive.
// It only guarantees that 'a' ... 'f' and 'A' ... 'F' are
// in increasing order, but the only two alternative encodings
// of the basic source character set that are still used by
// anyone today (ASCII and EBCDIC) make them consecutive.
unsigned char hexval(unsigned char c)
{
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9')
        return c - '0';
    else if ('a' <= c && c <= 'f')
        return c - 'a' + 10;
    else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'F')
        return c - 'A' + 10;
    else abort();
}
```

So to do the whole string looks something like this:

```
void hex2ascii(const string& in, string& out)
{
    out.clear();
    out.reserve(in.length() / 2);
    for (string::const_iterator p = in.begin(); p != in.end(); p++)
    {
       unsigned char c = hexval(*p);
       p++;
       if (p == in.end()) break; // incomplete last digit - should report error
       c = (c << 4) + hexval(*p); // + takes precedence over <<
       out.push_back(c);
    }
}
```

You might reasonably ask why one would do it this way when there's `strtol`, and using it is significantly less code (as in James Curran's answer).  Well, that approach is *a full decimal order of magnitude* slower, because it copies each two-byte chunk (possibly allocating heap memory to do so) and then invokes a general text-to-number conversion routine that cannot be written as efficiently as the specialized code above.  Christian's approach (using istringstream) is five times slower than *that*.  Here's a benchmark plot - you can tell the difference even with a tiny block of data to decode, and it becomes blatant as the differences get larger.  (Note that both axes are on a log scale.)

[image: Benchmark comparison plot]

Is this premature optimization?  Hell no.  This is the kind of operation that gets shoved in a library routine, forgotten about, and then called thousands of times a second.  It needs to scream.  I worked on a project a few years back that made very heavy use of SHA1 checksums internally -- we got 10-20% speedups on common operations by storing them as raw bytes instead of hex, converting only when we had to show them to the user -- and that was with conversion functions that had already been tuned to death.  One might honestly prefer brevity to performance here, depending on what the larger task is, but if so, why on earth are you coding in C++?

Also, from a pedagogical perspective, I think it's useful to show hand-coded examples for this kind of problem; it reveals more about what the computer has to do.

Comment: -1: ignored standard library facilities. I'd take of an extra point because they were mentioned in previous posts.

Comment: I ignored them because they're ten times slower than doing it by hand.  See edit.

Comment: +1 for focusing on performance, since this is likely to be something used frequently, like in a performance-critical loop. Also for realizing it is not the "correct" textbook answer, and recommending hiding it behind a library function. That's the best place for ugly code like this: behind a pretty interface.

Comment: +1 for the benchmark; though I think James and Christian's implementations are fine for where I am going to use this.

Answer (score 7):

```
std::string str("48656c6c6f");
std::string res;
res.reserve(str.size() / 2);
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i += 2)
{
    std::istringstream iss(str.substr(i, 2));
    int temp;
    iss >> std::hex >> temp;
    res += static_cast<char>(temp);
}
std::cout << res;
```

Comment: Could pre-allocate, length is known in advance!

Comment: I hate to say it, but this is five times slower than the accepted answer (which is itself ten times slower than my answer).

Comment: @Zack: I edited my answer and pre-allocate the size of the output string like Caron mentioned and you already did. I'm interested what now are the performance differences between my solution and yours?

Comment: My benchmark program preallocated the output string for all three cases; the only difference was the code inside the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

[strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) should do the job if you add `0x` to each hex digit pair.

Comment: You don't need the 0x, you just need to pass 16 as the third argument.  But strtol is massive overkill for this job...

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, only wanted to give a quick response, this is of course not the best solution (especially for C++).