# C++ Giving string as consecutive (unreadable) characters in hex value

Tags: c++, string, hex

I am doing a project with string encryption.

The encrypted strings and a pseudo code to decrypt/encrypt (symmetric) those strings are given in a pdf. Example of one string entry: (first character always unencrypted)

crypt 'kÜìæÜô¦-Ðøôô'; hex '6b9a8d919a93cccdd19b9393'; clear 'kernel32.dll'

...

Clear text is only given for a few strings. I need to fill in the rest.

The readable string does not "match" the hex representation. If I copy & paste it in my IDE, the hex values differ (except from first letter).
So I think its best to copy the hex representation in my IDE and transform it to a string.
The pseudo code for encryption is very easy and not part of the question here.

How to give a string or character array in C++ with consecutive hex representation?
Solution with easy copy & paste from given pdf preferred.

Current solution with std::stringstream is not working as intended, as I get the given hex values as strings:

```
std::stringstream ss;

ss << std::hex <<  0x6b<< 0x9a << 0x8d << 0x91 << 0x9A << 0x93 << 0xCC << 0xCD << 0xD1 << 0x9B << 0x93 << 0x93;
```

Comment: `ss << (char)0x6b` ?

Comment: `ss << '\x6b'`?

Comment: or if you want to be able to have one long string of hexpairs as input, write a parser for it e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3790613/4386278

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question include also output and expected output. The code you did post makes `ss` contain the expected string: https://godbolt.org/z/1ePWhj

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 That is not the expected string.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings its what I expected, what OP expects I don't understand

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 What you expect doesn't matter, it's what the OP expects that we're here for  The phrase _"not working as intended, as I get the given hex values as strings:"_ tells me that the hex values as strings is _not_ what they want.

Comment: I do agree we need a clearer question with respect to exactly what sort of input values/workflow the OP is after.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings yes I read it again and understand that thats not what OP excepts, but I still dont know for sure what they expect instead. Will read it again...

Comment: Formatted output of integers with `<<` produces the string representation of the integers; all `std::hex` does is change the string representation from decimal to hexadecimal form (and `0x6b` denotes the same integer as `107`). You need `char`s with the same values.