# How to generate a secure random STRING (Key and IV) for AES-256-CBC WinApi ? [C/C++]

Tags: c++, aes, encryption-symmetric

I need to generate (in C/C++) a secure random string (32byte) to use as Key and another (16byte) to use as IV for AES-256-CBC encryption using WinApi. The problem is that I need to save the generated string in a text file in order to manually test the decryption using OpenSSL in terminal.
What can I use to generate the secure random string other than [CryptGenRandom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom)? The problem of CryptGenRandom is that it generates a random byte sequence that I can't save/use as OpenSSL input because it's not an ASCII text:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -K "..." -iv ".." -in encrypted.txt
```

Is there an alternative?

This is my working code:

```
// handles for csp and key
HCRYPTPROV hProv = NULL;
HCRYPTKEY hKey = NULL;
BYTE *szKey = (BYTE*)calloc(DEFAULT_AES_KEY_SIZE + 1, sizeof(BYTE));
BYTE *szIV = (BYTE*)calloc(DEFAULT_IV_SIZE + 1, sizeof(BYTE));
char* ciphertext= 0;
DWORD dwPlainSize = lstrlenA(*plaintext), dwBufSize = 0;
AES256KEYBLOB AESBlob;
memset(&AESBlob, 0, sizeof(AESBlob));

// initalize key and plaintext
StrCpyA((LPSTR)szKey, "00112233445566778899001122334455");
StrCpyA((LPSTR)szIV, "4455667788990011");
// generate key & IV
//if (!CryptGenRandom(hProv, DEFAULT_AES_KEY_SIZE, szKey)) {goto error;}
//if (!CryptGenRandom(hProv, DEFAULT_IV_SIZE, szIV)) {goto error;}

// blob data for CryptImportKey() function (include key and version and so on...)
AESBlob.bhHdr.bType = PLAINTEXTKEYBLOB;
AESBlob.bhHdr.bVersion = CUR_BLOB_VERSION;
AESBlob.bhHdr.reserved = 0;
AESBlob.bhHdr.aiKeyAlg = CALG_AES_256;
AESBlob.dwKeySize = DEFAULT_AES_KEY_SIZE;
StrCpyA((LPSTR)AESBlob.szBytes, (LPCSTR)szKey);

// create a cryptographic service provider (CSP)
if (!CryptAcquireContextA(&hProv, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV_A, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {goto error;}

// populate crypto provider (CSP)
if (!CryptImportKey(hProv, (BYTE*)&AESBlob, sizeof(AES256KEYBLOB), NULL, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE, &hKey)) { goto error; }
if (!CryptSetKeyParam(hKey, KP_IV, szIV, 0)) { goto error; }

// ciphertext allocation
dwBufSize = BUFFER_FOR_PLAINTEXT + dwPlainSize;
ciphertext = (char*)calloc(dwBufSize, sizeof(char));
memcpy_s(ciphertext, dwBufSize, *plaintext, dwPlainSize);

// encryption
if (!CryptEncrypt(hKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, (BYTE*)ciphertext, &dwPlainSize, dwBufSize) ) { goto error; }
```

Comment: The IV doesn't need to be secured. You can use the same one, e.g. all zeros, from now until Armageddon without fear.

Answer (score 0):

The key and IV are given to OpenSSL as hexadecimal. There's no need to generate visible ASCII characters only. You could have figured that out yourself just by pretending that the generated key and IV was "Hello". You get an error message that's pretty helpful.

```
$> openssl aes-256-cbc -d -K Hello -iv Hello
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
non-hex digit
invalid hex iv value
```

And hey, look at your code,

```
// initalize key and plaintext
StrCpyA((LPSTR)szKey, "00112233445566778899001122334455");
StrCpyA((LPSTR)szIV, "4455667788990011");
```

These string are not only ASCII text, they happen to be hex as well. It looks to as if you just need to [convert hex to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790613/how-to-convert-a-string-of-hex-values-to-a-string) in your code or [convert bytes to a hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050452/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-visual-c) if you have the bytes in code and want to generate the command line.

Comment: Why hex to bytes? I want to generate a random string as the commented CryptGenRandom line (not the hex string "00112233445566778899001122334455" and "4455667788990011" used as test).
If I use CryptGenRandom I have a string of bytes, so I need to convert bytes to hex.
Is it ok? Is it true that the converted hex string is still random+secure?

Comment: @rmroot: I added a link to code that does the reverse as well. The conversion into hex will not change anything. It is just a different encoding of the same data. It will neither affect randomness nor security. If I say "A" to you or 65 (decimal) or 0x41 (hex) or 0b01000001 (binary) or &#65; (XML), it's still just an "A".