# C++ hex string to unsigned int

Tags: c++, hex, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ convert hex string to signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer)

I'm trying to convert a hex string to an unsigned int in C++. My code looks like this:

```
string hex("FFFF0000");
UINT decimalValue;
sscanf(hex.c_str(), "%x", &decimalValue); 
printf("\nstring=%s, decimalValue=%d",hex.c_str(),decimalValue);
```

The result is -65536 though. I don't typically do too much C++ programming, so any help would be appreciated.

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Also see [Convert hexadecimal string with leading “0x” to signed short in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1487440/608639)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

output with int with `%u` instead of `%d`

Comment: isn't this just the opposite? e.g. converting int to hex string?

Answer (score 25):

You can do this using an `istringstream` and the `hex` manipulator:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::istringstream converter("FFFF0000");
unsigned int value;
converter >> std::hex >> value;
```

You can also use the `std::oct` manipulator to parse octal values.

I think the reason that you're getting negative values is that you're using the `%d` format specifier, which is for signed values.  Using `%u` for unsigned values should fix this.  Even better, though, would be to use the streams library, which figures this out at compile-time:

```
std::cout << value << std::endl; // Knows 'value' is unsigned.
```

Comment: Does anyone know what happens here if the number is not valid hex? I just tried letters such as 0xG, and I didn't catch an exception?

Comment: @gbmhunter That will cause the stream to enter a fail state, which doesn't necessarily trigger an exception unless you've enabled them. You might want to read up on `failbit` and stream failures.

Answer (score 4):

Well, -65536 is 0xFFFF0000. If you'll use

```
printf("\nstring=%s, decimalValue=%u",hex.c_str(),decimalValue);
```

it will print what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

`%d` interprets the bits of the UINT as signed. You need:

```
printf("\nstring=%s, decimalValue=%u",hex.c_str(),decimalValue);
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is right, 0xffff0000 is -65536 if interpreted as signed (the %d printf formatter).  You want your hex number interpreted as unsigned (%u or %x).