# Read hex text format 0x from stream

Tags: c++, text, stream, hex

I'm looking for a simple method to read a hex value from a text file using streams.  I searched Stack Overflow using "C++ hex read stream 0x" and most of responses were about writing hex as text or reading in hex values without the "0x" prefix.  This question is about reading the hex number, with "0x" prefix as a number in one operation.

My method:

```
unsigned char byte;
std::istringstream sample("0xce");
sample >> std::hex >> byte;
```

Ends up with `byte` containing '0' (0x30) from the first character.

The 'strtol` function handles the conversion, but requires reading the data, converting to C-style string.

I'm overloading the `operator>>` in a class to read a comma separated value (CSV) text file.  Here is a sample of the data file:

```
1,-4.93994892,0xa5,8,115.313e+3,
2,-4.93986238,0xc0,8,114.711e+3,
3,-4.93977554,0xc2,8,114.677e+3,
```

My extraction method:

```
class Csv_Entry
{
public:
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& inp, Csv_Entry& ce);
    unsigned int    m_index;
    double      m_time;
    unsigned char   m_byte;
    unsigned int    m_data_length;
    double      m_bit_rate;
};

std::istream&
operator >> (std::istream& inp, Csv_Entry& ce)
{
    char    separator;
    inp >> ce.m_index;
    inp >> separator;
    inp >> ce.m_time;
    inp >> separator;
    inp >> std::hex >> ce.m_byte;
    inp >> separator;
    inp >> ce.m_data_length;
    inp >> separator;
    inp >> ce.m_bit_rate;
    inp.ignore(10000, '\n');
    return inp;
}
```

Do I need to use `std::setw`?

**Edit 1:**
I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Premium on Windows 7, 64-bit platform.

Comment: you can save yourself a trouble of parsing cvs file yourself and use ready parser generator that's flexible enough to handle all cases (including unicode): http://tinyurl.com/3zs2o6k

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev:  Thanks for the suggestion.  I have always thought that parsers were overkill for simple CSV files.  I would use a parser if there was a language involved, or a complex protocol.  This program is a small analyzer and I think that a parser would make the program too complex.

Comment: Related, see [Convert hexadecimal string with leading “0x” to signed short in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1487440/608639)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solution is to read the value using an `unsigned int` then convert to `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned int value;
inp >> hex >> value;
unsigned char byte;
byte = value & 0xFF;
```

I guess there is something about the type `unsigned char` that is causing the issue.

Any C++ language lawyers can quote a section that describes this behavior?

Comment: it's a text stream, chars are read as symbols, not values; thus '0' is read as a char with value 0x30.

Comment: Yup, it's the `int` data type instead of `char` that makes the difference here.  `showbase` does not affect the input streams, per spec.  I'm not sure which compilers this will work in, see this thread for some samples: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/540229-simple-question-of-integer-input-c/

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev:  Are *unsigned* characters still read as symbols (characters)?  I'm from the embedded systems world and we use `unsigned char` as a numeric type, not as a character.

Comment: @Thomas -- the stream is text, operator>> is overloaded for all char types (singed/unsigned, charT)

Comment: See 27.7.2.2.3/12 where all these overloads mentioned

Comment: C++03 §27.6.1.2.2 [lib.istream.formatted.arithmetic] says that for arithmetic types, the extractor uses the locale's `num_get<>` object to parse the input stream.  According to §22.2.2.1/2 [lib.facet.num.get.virtuals], the characters are interpreted according to `scanf` with an appropriate format specifier (Tables 55-56), which is `%X` for `unsigned int`.  However, `char` and `unsigned char` are not considered arithmetic types; their behavior is described by §27.6.1.2.3.

Comment: Per @Adam Rosenfield's comment, `char` and especially `unsigned char` are not considered arithmetic types, but they can be used in arithmetic expressions.  Go Figure!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the data-type for your `m_byte` member of `Csv_Entry`.  When going through input-stream extraction for your input data, it's interpreting the `0` as a valid value, then interpreting the `x` as a separator, and therefore throwing off the rest of the values in the stream-extraction.  If you change your `Csv_Entry::m_byte` member to an `unsigned int`, the problem goes away, and it interprets the hex-value properly using `std::hex`.

BTW, since all your members are public, you might as well make `Csv_Entry` a structure, but here is some sample working code using your entry data: http://ideone.com/H7NG1

You'll notice on the output side, I only need to include `std::hex` and `std::showbase` to get the hex values to print correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Thomas Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225074/thomas-matthews) right. You have to convert from `unsigned int` to `unsigned char`.

If you are convenient with C-functions `scanf/printf` you'll notice that they behave similar. But they are more descriptive for this situations I think.

```
//%X specifies that we trying read integer in format 0x123FFF
//%c specifies that we trying read character
//0xABC is input string

unsigned char hex;
sscanf("0xABC", "%X", &hex); // error because not enough memory allocated
                             // by address &hex to store integer

unsigned char hex;
sscanf("0xABC", "%c", &hex); // reads only one character '0'
```

So my point is that you can either read a hexadecimal integer or read character, but you trying to "read hexadecimal integer in character". So specific case for stdlib developers )