# how to convert ascii to unsigned int

Tags: c++

Is there a method that converts string to unsigned int?
_ultoa exists but couldn't find the vise verse version...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`std::strtoul()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) is the one. And then again there are the old ones like `atoi()`.

Comment: atoi doesn't do unsigned though, right?  In the Windows CRT, it will return an error (ERANGE) in the event of overflow.

Comment: Cheeso, yes, for what I can tell by the "i", it's int ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Boost provides lexical_cast.

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
[...]
unsigned int x = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned int>(strVal);
```

Alternatively, you can use a stringstream (which is basically what lexical_cast does under the covers):

```
#include <sstream>
[...]
std::stringstream s(strVal);
unsigned int x;
s >> x;
```

Comment: And if you want non-decimal interpretation, see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer

Comment: Am I the only person who loves stream insertion, but hates stream extraction? I'd use functions (such as this boost one, though to be honest I'd probably still use atoi without thinking) every time.

Comment: Yeah, stream extraction is pretty ugly, especially since you can't initialise constants with it.  It is also quite a bit more powerful though, as you can use manipulators to change your base, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) will do what you want.

```
char* myString = "123";  // Declare a string (c-style)
unsigned int myNumber;   // a number, where the answer will go.

sscanf(myString, "%u", &myNumber);  // Parse the String into the Number

printf("The number I got was %u\n", myNumber);  // Show the number, hopefully 123
```

Comment: I hated the scanf family even back in C. It never did what I wanted it to do, and most times it caused a bug. It's OK if you know that the string matches your requirements - if you've already checked it or extracted it with other code - but in that case, why not just use atoi or whatever?

Anyone using a scanf-family function - well, there are some crimes where no punishment can ever be too harsh ;-)

Comment: That should be "Anyone using a scanf-family function in C++ - ..."

Answer (score 0):

It works if you go via _atoi64

unsigned long l = _atoi64(str);

Answer (score -3):

How about [int **atoi** ( const char * str )](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) ?

```
string s("123");
unsigned u = (unsigned)atoi(s.c_str());
```

Comment: This is not a good suggestion at all.  He's specifically asked for "unsigned int" and mentions things like "_ultoa".  The poster knows about atoi(), atol(), etc.  These functions are all signed and recognize the - symbol, might handle overflow, etc.   The right answer is to use functions like strtoul.