# convert string into signed int

Tags: c, string, int, signed

I want to convert a string into a signed int. Following is the requirement. I have stored hex value as a string in buffer. Now I want to convert that value into signed int.

`buf = "fb869e"` Convert this into signed int. So o/p should be -293218. but when I'm trying to convert using strtol I'm getting 16483998. So what I should I do?

Comment: Where did you get that 0xfb869e is -293218? strtol is actually right.

Comment: i think it's evident its C, he's using `strtol()`.

Comment: why output should be  -293218? strtol return type  is long int, btw.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ convert hex string to signed integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer)

Answer (score 5):

The hexadecimal number `0xfb869e` is **not** negative.  The inbuilt number conversion functions will not convert it to a negative value, since its value is positive.

What you are saying is that this is the unsigned hexadecimal equivalent of a 24-bit 2s complement negative number, and you want that number.  The way to get that is to convert it to the positive number, then use calculations to convert it to the 24-bit 2s complement equivalent:

```
char *buf = "fb869e";
long n;

n = strtol(buf, NULL, 16);
if (n > 0x7fffffL)
    n -= 0x1000000L;
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have suggested `strtol()`.  I just want to mention `sscanf()` as an alternative, eg:

```
int i;
char *buf = "fb869e";
if (sscanf(buf, "%x", &i) == 1)
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
0xfb869e == 0x00fb869e == 16483998
```

As a signed integer, the high bit must be set to produce a negative number. Since the high bit of the given number isn't set, it must be positive.

If you want the number to be treated as a 24-bit number, you'll have to pad bit 23 out to the remaining high-bits. Here's one way to do it:

```
long n = strtol(...);
if (n > 0xffffff) n |= 0xff000000;
```

Comment: char buf = "fb869e" - I want to convert into signed int. The o/p should be -293218. I just tried converting string into long int. But I'm not getting the negative value.

Comment: char buf = "fb869e". I want to convert this into signed int. So o/p should be -293218. I just tried converting string into long using strtol. But I'm not getting the negative values. My hex values are follows. I need o/p in signed int. "C programming"
80000e
fcc15e
7ffffe
0b778e
80000e
ee4dae
7ffffe
1b1e5e
80000e
de2b9e
7ffffe
2b8c4e
80000e
ce2e1e
7ffffe

Comment: @ulganathan: There was a bug in my answer. Use `if (n > 0x7fffff)...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

strtol converts string to long integer

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/

The output is correct and it will be 16483998

And if you use atoi, while it converts to string to integer, the correct value if out of the range of representable values, INT_MAX or INT_MIN is returned.

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/

Answer (score 0):

why should 0x00fb869e be a negative number? you should have to provide the base of your number system, to even be allowed to tell, whether a value in one format is a negative in another format

Comment: char buf = "fb869e". I want to convert this into signed int. So o/p should be -293218. My hex values are follows. I need o/p in signed int.
80000e
fcc15e
7ffffe
0b778e
80000e
ee4dae
7ffffe
1b1e5e
80000e
de2b9e
7ffffe
2b8c4e
80000e
ce2e1e
7ffffe

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtol` which converts `string` to a `long` integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below block of code, its working for me.

```
char *p = "0x820";
uint16_t intVal;
sscanf(p, "%x", &intVal);

printf("value x: %x - %d", intVal, intVal);

Output is:

value x: 820 - 2080
```