# How to convert a string containting the hex value of a UTF-8 to a wchar in C?

Tags: c, string, unicode, hex, wchar

I am using GCC. I have a string containing the hex value of a UTF-8 char like this:

```
char[] str = "4e86"
```

(such kind of strings are read out from an xml-file).
I would like this to convert this to a wchar containing the character \u4e86.

I know I can directly define

```
wchar_t wc = L'\u4e86';
```

but I would like a function like this

```
wchar_t wc = convert(str)
```

How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
char[] str = "4e86";
wchar_t wc = strtol(str, NULL, 16);
```

(ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10156436/999400)