# Store string value in int

Tags: c, string

I am reading hex value from strings like

```
char *str = "0xF";
```

Now I want to store this value in an `int` type to pass that int variable in the function. What would be the correct method to do it?

**Edit**I dont want to convert this from hex to decimal but the function requires value in form of hex only. So i want to change this char* into int.

Comment: This has been [asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156409/convert-hex-string-char-to-int) =)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strtol` function with the base as 16 to convert from hexadecimal string to integer. read this to know about [strtol](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtol.htm)