# Arduino: Convert a String hex "#FFFFFF" into 3 int

Tags: c++, c, arduino, hex

I'm completely new to C/C++ and I am trying to figure out how to convert a String argument that would be in the form of a html style rgb hex such as "#ffffff" and turn that into 3 integers vars

I'm really not sure where to being.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All you need to do is convert the string to integers and then split them into three separate r, g, b values.

```
string hexstring = "#FF3Fa0";

// Get rid of '#' and convert it to integer
int number = (int) strtol( &hexstring[1], NULL, 16);

// Split them up into r, g, b values
int r = number >> 16;
int g = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
int b = number & 0xFF;
```

You may want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156409/convert-hex-string-char-to-int) as well.

---

**Edit (thanks to James comments):**

For some machine (e.g. Arduino (Uno)), ints are 16 bits instead of 32. If red values are dropping for you, use a long instead.

```
string hexstring = "#FF3Fa0";

// Get rid of '#' and convert it to integer
long number = strtol( &hexstring[1], NULL, 16);

// Split them up into r, g, b values
long r = number >> 16;
long g = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
long b = number & 0xFF;
```

---

**Edit (an even safer version, use `strtoll` instead of `strtol`):**

```
long long number = strtoll( &hexstring[1], NULL, 16);

// Split them up into r, g, b values
long long r = number >> 16;
long long g = number >> 8 & 0xFF;
long long b = number & 0xFF;
```

Comment: This one looks the best to me so far but the problem is I'm starting with a type of String and I'm getting cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*'

Comment: You can convert a string to `const char*` by the following `string v1 = "#FF3Fa0"; const char* v2 = v1.c_str()`. And also, this `&hexstring[1]` simply means that you take the address of  `hexstring[1]`, it doesn't matter whether it is `string` or `const char*`. I have modified the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Yuchen! I want to note that for my Arduino (Uno) ints are 16 bit instead of 32. If red values are dropping for you, try using a long instead.

Comment: @James, this is very helpful! Thank you. I added your comments in the answer.

Comment: when i run 
string hexstring = "#FF3Fa0"; i get 'string' was not declared in scope

Comment: @JimTrue please add `#include <string>`

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to parse your value. You may do that this way:

```
void parse_hex(char* a, char* b, char* c, const char* string) {
    //certainly not the most elegant way. Note that we start at 1 because of '#'
    a[0] = string[1];
    a[1] = string[2];
    b[0] = string[3];
    b[1] = string[4];
    c[0] = string[5];
    c[1] = string[6];
}
```

Then, you will convert each string into it's correspondent integer. You can learn how to do that from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070499/3114237) answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   char const* str = "#FF9922";
   char red[5] = {0};
   char green[5] = {0};
   char blue[5] = {0};

   red[0] = green[0] = blue[0] = '0';
   red[1] = green[1] = blue[1] = 'X';

   red[2] = str[1];
   red[3] = str[2];

   green[2] = str[3];
   green[3] = str[4];

   blue[2] = str[5];
   blue[3] = str[6];

   int r = strtol(red, NULL, 16);
   int g = strtol(green, NULL, 16);
   int b = strtol(blue, NULL, 16);

   std::cout << "Red: " << r << ", Green: " << g << ", Blue: " << b << std::endl;
}
```