# Convert char* to uint16_t in C

Tags: c, linux

I have char array like

```
char* str = 0x058f;
```

What should i do to convert this value to int and uint16_t and print correctly this value by uint16_t type?

That mean i want the uint16_t result is 058f as well:

```
 uint16_t result = 0x058f;
```

Comment: ["What is the XY problem?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Do you mean to convert `char* str = "0x058f";`?  Review `sscanf()` and `SCNx16` from `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: this problem doesn't show any research effort at all. google `c hex to int`, bunches of answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156409/convert-hex-string-char-to-int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> convert this value to int and uint16_t and print correctly this value by uint16_t

```
int main(void) {

  char* str = "0x058f";

  int i;
  unsigned u;
  if (sscanf(str, "%x", &u) != 1) 
    Handle_Failure();
  i = (int) u;

  uint16_t u16;
  if (sscanf(str, "%" SCNx16, &u16) != 1) 
    Handle_Failure();

  printf("i: 0x%04x  i16: 0x%04" PRIx16 "\n", i, u16);
  return 0;
}

i: 0x058f  i16: 0x058f
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i got it ~

Answer (score 2):

You can use strtol to convert string to integer value

```
*char* str = "0x058f";
result = strtol(str,NULL,16);
printf("result = %x\n",result);*
```

I hope this helps.