# take a char with a hex value and return the value as an integer

Tags: c

I build this function that take a char with a hex value and return the value as an integer, the hex char value can star with `0x` or `0X` and could has lower or upper char, you must check if is a correct hex value if not return -1.

I am asking if you can improve this code or do it in a more efficient way, I can't use c or another library just use the c core. Just c no c++.

```
long long unsigned int atoi_hexadecimal(char s[])
{
    long long unsigned int num = 0;
    long long unsigned int size = 0;
    long long unsigned i=0;

    while(s[i]!='\0')
        i++;
    size=i;


    for(i=0 ; (((s[i]>='0') && (s[i]<='9')) || ((s[i]>='A') && (s[i]<='F')) || ((s[i]>='a') && (s[i]<='f')) || ((s[i]=='x') || (s[i]=='X'))); ++i)
    {
        if((i==0) && (s[i]!='0'))
            return -1;
        else if ((i==1) && (s[i]!='x') && (s[i]!='X'))
            return -1;
        else if ((s[i]>='A') && (s[i]<='F'))
                num = num + (s[i]-'A'+10)*power(16,size-i-1);
        else if ((s[i]>='a') && (s[i]<='f'))
                num = num + (s[i]-'a'+10)*power(16,size-i-1);
        else if ((s[i]>='0') && (s[i]<='9') && (i!=0))
                num = num + (s[i]-'0')*power(16,size-i-1);
        else if ((i!=0) && (s[i]!=0) && (s[i]!='x') && (s[i]!='X'))
            return -1;
    }

    if(i==size)
        return num;
    else return -1;
}

double power(double base, double exp)
{
    double p=1;

    for(int i=0; i<exp; i++)
    {
        p=p*base;
    }

    return p;
}
```

Example of use

```
printf("%llu \n",atoi_hexadecimal("0XF15"));
```

Can anybody improve this code for transform char that contain a hex to int value or do it in another way?

Comment: You declare this `long long unsigned int atoi_hexadecimal` and then you do this `return -1;`.  Are you sure you know what are you doing there?

Comment: Those `else if` where you have there `num = num + (s[i]-'A'+10)*power(16,size-i-1);` you do realize that you have a conversion problem in there....

Comment: One last thing `double power(double base, double exp);`, why did you call it `power` ?

Comment: And the (very) last thing, `Can anybody improve this code`, why should someone here on SO waste their time for you??

Comment: i just looking to improve my code, what some one would waste time for me? because is a site for answer question if you don't wanna answer then don't do it i am not paying for this. Thanks for the advices, i would like to see another opinions from other programmers

Comment: num = num + (s[i]-'A'+10)*power(16,size-i-1); the conversion problem is because the power function return? i Called power because math called pow just fast tip, the long long unsigned is because hex can hold bigger integers with a shorter syntax

Comment: `(s[i]!=0)` --> `(s[i]!='0')` ?

Comment: We are not a coding or code review service.

Comment: @Michi Well, people are doing this on SE network. It's just not the right one.

Comment: Well, I would be tempted to use a [256] const byte lookup table to convert the hex char to nibble or error, (0xFF).  Lookup, check, shift, lookup, check, shift...

Comment: `long long unsigned int size = 0;
 long long unsigned i=0;

    while(s[i]!='\0')
        i++;
    size=i;` would be better replaced by `size_t size = strlen(s); unsigned long long int i = 0;`.  I have reservations about `unsigned long long int` in use for indexes, if only because `size_t` is more compact and at least as correct.  And you shouldn't need to use `double` values to produce your answer — use integer arithmetic only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long int strtol(const char *str, char **endptr, int base)
```

will help you

Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156409/convert-hex-string-char-to-int)
and [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strtol.html)

just make sure that your input is correct and go on

Answer (score 0):

there are functions for that if you `#include <stdlib.h>`. Put in `16` as the radix.