# What is the best way to parse a string that has names, hex values, etc.?

Tags: c, parsing

Basically, I have a file which contains multiple lines that I have to parse. For example, I may have something of the form: "Homer Simpson ate @0x000000000000BEEF donuts"

Recovering the name is simple, it's recovering the number of donuts he ate that I have trouble with. In other words, I would like to store this number in a uint64_t variable.

My first approach was to simply read the number from character to character and convert it to a decimal (i.e. I would compute 0*16^15 + 0*16^14 + ... + E *16^1 + F*16^0). This method seems very costly to me and I am sure there must be a better way for me to achieve this. However, this technique had the advantage that if the number was written like this "@0x0000 0000 0000 BEEF", I would still be able to convert it to a uint64_t variable.

The second method I tried was to use sscanf or strol (as described in many other posts, such as this one: [Convert hex string (char []) to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156409/convert-hex-string-char-to-int)). The problem with this method is that I first have to create a substring "@0x000000000000BEEF" from the original string (same goes for strol). Again, this technique works, but it wouldn't work if I had "@0x0000 0000 0000 BEEF.

Is there a clever and easy way for me to recover this number and store it in a uint64_t variable?

This question is not the same as in other posts. All they have to do it to convert a hex string into a uint64_t. My question is different.

I have a string which is not simply composed of the hex-value,  the format of the hex-value may changes from line to line and may have whitespace separated words. For example, I may have:

```
"Bart annoyed @00000000000000AA people today"
```

Or the hex value may be written like this:

```
"Bart annoyed @0000 0000 0000 00AA people today"
```

How can I read each line a form the hex number as a string that can then be converted as shown in the other answers?

Comment: Doesn't seem like the duplicate is correct, but the question is vague too.. *what exactly* do you expect to be matched here... How about *"Homer Simpson ate @0x000000000000 beef briskets?"*

Comment: What do you mean exactly by match? Essentially, I have a hexadecimal value composed of sixteen characters (in your example that would be "@0x000000000000 beef" ) and I would like to convert it to a uint64_t variable. Now each line could be different as I could have a line of the form " Marge spent @0xAAAAAAAAAAAA0000 on groceries "

Comment: Nothing is easy when it comes to parsing with C.

Comment: Do you have any ideas then ?

Comment: I wouldn't even use `sscanf`, just a state machine with `fgetc` and then read all `isxdigit` ones into a buffer of 17+ and when it is full then `strtoull` but that hardly counts as "easy"

Comment: then is my approach wrong? Because, essentially, what I did was to store each line in a string.... Maybe that was a bad idea

Comment: if it spans a line? `sscanf` is very brittle too... Mine would work with `@0x0000 0000 0000 BEEF`, if you skip any `isspace` ...

Comment: It cannot span a line, I made sure to remove the \n from the line

Comment: even then, there is no standard library routine that could read `0x0000 0000 0000 BEEF` with spaces in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scanset could be used with `sscanf` to capture the portion of the line up to the @.
Then scan `@0x` and use `%n` to get the number of characters processed to use as an index for further processing.
Use `%1x%n` to scan each hex digit and count the characters processed. This will iterate through the line skipping spaces. Add the number of scanned characters to `index` and iterate through the line using `input + index`.
Incorporate each hex digit into the hex value. This shifts the value and `or`'s the digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define SIZE 100
//so SIZE can be part of sscanf Format String
#define SSFS(x) #x
#define FS(x) SSFS(x)


int main( void) {
    char input[SIZE + 1] = "Homer Simpson ate @0x0000 0000 0000 B E E F donuts";
    char name[SIZE + 1] = "";
    int index = 0;
    int scanned = 0;
    int digit = 0;
    uint64_t hex = 0;
    unsigned int hexdigit = 0;

    sscanf ( input, "%"FS(SIZE)"[^@]@0x%n", name, &index);
    if ( index) {
        while ( digit < 16 && 1 == sscanf ( input + index, "%1x%n", &hexdigit, &scanned)) {
            digit++;
            index += scanned;
            hex <<= 4;
            hex |= hexdigit;
        }
        printf ( "name [%s] [%" PRIu64 "] [%s]\n", name, hex, input + index);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much