# Converting Hex address in char array to uint8_t

Tags: c, char, uint8t

The problem:

- I have a char array `char myCharArray[] = "0x77"` that I need to convert to become the same as `uint8_t = 0x77`.

I have tried all sort of things but ran out of ides. Can this be done, and if so can I get some help please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems exactly what you need: [Convert hex string (char \[\]) to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156409/convert-hex-string-char-to-int)

Answer (score 0):

@Marco Bonelli, Thank you it worked. The following solved my problem:

`uint8_t addr = (uint8_t)strtol(buffer, NULL, 0);`