# How do I get a char from a hex code stored in a character pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers, hex

How can I get a char in C that corresponds with a hex code stored in a character pointer?

For example, in the below, I have "2A" in char pointer hex.  **How do I get the * character from this?**

```
int main() {  
char* hex = "2A";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156409/convert-hex-string-char-to-int

Comment: Use `strtoul` function.

Comment: Marked it as a duplicate since "converting" an int to char is trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `strtol`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    char *hex = "2A";
    printf("%c\n", (int)strtol(hex, NULL, 16));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%c` expects an `int` and not `char`