# String to HEX conversion

Tags: c#, hex, complement

Given the following:

```
string var1 = "0206"
string var2 = "020C"
string result = "FFFA"
```

I need to take the twos complement of the hex representation of var2 [((FFFF-VAR2)+1)] And add it to the hex representation of var1. The result will be a string representation of the hex result (FFFA).  I don't know how to convert the string vars so that I can perform the computations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792610/convert-string-into-signed-int

Comment: `uint v = Convert.ToUInt32(yourString, 16);`

Comment: yeah, thanks... didn't search correctly