# Conversion of 32-bit Hex to integer

Tags: integer, hex

I want to convert 32-bit Hex to integer in 'C'

seqBuf = "81BD82E8" This is the Hex value I'm getting and stored in a buffer

The corresponding value of that hex value is 2176680680

How to convert? Please help me....

Is there any function "strtoull()" as like strtoul()...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm assuming you're looking for a C function?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer

Answer (score 1):

```
char *seqBuf = "81BD82E8", *end;
unsigned long x = strtoul(seqBuf, &end, 16);
printf("longVal= %u\n", x);
```