# How do I convert a string representation of a hex to its hex value in c?

Tags: c

If I have

```
char input[50] = "xFFFF";
int a;
```

How can I store the numerical value of input in a?
the language is C.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it might be:

```
if (sscanf(input, "x%x", &a) == 0) {
    /* matching failed */
}
```

If your input uses a real hex specifier (like "0xFFFF") you can just use %i:

```
if (sscanf(input, "%i", &a) == 0) {
    /* matching failed */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use strtol function

```
char *ptr;
long a = strtol( input, &ptr, 16 );
```

Comment: skip over the first character though, if it's known to be X. strtol might not understand that X, it should understand the prefix 0x though.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I wrote common case of using strtol.

Comment: For known hex, you should use `strtoul` (unsigned long)

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char *p="xFFFF";
   long lng=strtol(&p[1], (char **)0, 16);
   printf("%ld\n", lng);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [C++ convert hex string to signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer) and if you're in a pure C environment, make sure to scroll down.

Comment: @cdhowie @nos You've got to read the whole post, not just the title.

Comment: @Michael: Which part of the question implies that this is C++?

Comment: @cdhowie This isn't C++. That is clear. But the post that I referenced covers solutions for C++ and plain C. Read it.

Comment: @Michael: Sorry, those are all C++.  Some of them reference C functions by way of `#include <cstdlib>`, but none are actually written in C.

Comment: @cdhowie: If you ignore the `cout` stuff the two answers that deal with `strtol` and `strtoul` are pure C.

Comment: @Michael: You would have been better to post a code snippet showing the pure C code using `strtoul`.

Comment: @Software Monkey: Sure, but if I'm reading between the lines of the question here, the OP is not very familiar with C or C++, and would have a hard time distinguishing C code from C++ code.