# C++ - Convert Char Array To Hex

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, arduino, arduino-uno

I am working on a school project using `Arduino`, I have no past experience with `C++`, and I want to generate a unique `MAC Address` for every chip. Now I have built a function that creates a two dimensional `char` array containing the unique `MAC`. And it returns something like this:

```
// 2D char array example:
char mac[6][2] = {{'A', 'B'}, {'4', 'D'}, {'F', '5'}, {'C', '9'}, {'B', '7'}, {'F', '2'}};
```

And I want to convert it to something like this:

```
// Hex array example:
byte mac[6] = {0xAB, 0x4D, 0xF5, 0xC9, 0xB7, 0xF2};
```

**Important Note: Arduino does not support `STL` so I need an implementation that does not use it.**

How to achieve this result?

> This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457551/hex-character-to-int-in-c).

Comment: Hint `first_value_as_decimal * 16 + second_value_as_decimal` equals the the same value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hex character to int in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457551/hex-character-to-int-in-c)

Comment: @NathanOliver Do you mean that: `byte mac[6] = {171, 77, 261, 201, 183, 258};` is the same array as above?

Comment: @paler123 I can't use `STL` so it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @AmeerTaweel 10 * 16 + 11 is not 21.

Comment: @AmeerTaweel `A` as a decimal is 10, `B` is 11, 10 * 16 + 11 != 21.  It is 171

Comment: @paler123 not an exact duplicate though the posting you reference provides the first step in the conversion. OP needs to do the conversion to hex of each character in the pairs then combine the two characters of a pair into a single byte. So after converting each of two characters into hex value next shift one of the resulting nibble values (0x0 - 0xf) to the upper nibble then bitwise OR the two values together. Shift by either multiple times 16 or do left shift with `<<` operator by 8.

Comment: @molbdnilo I edited the comment, is it right now?

Comment: This array, is the same result that I want? `byte mac[6] = {171, 77, 261, 201, 183, 258};`

Comment: 261 != F5 and 258 != F2.  F5 = 15*16+5

Comment: @NathanOliver now I get it: `byte mac[6] = {171, 77, 245, 201, 183, 242};`, please post an answer so I can vote for you.

Comment: Why wouldn't Arduino support the standard library? I use it there all the time.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz you can read this: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/24790/is-the-c-stl-fully-supported-on-arduino

Comment: @AmeerTaweel That just says it's not included in the Arduino IDE, noting about Arduino not supporting it.

Comment: @gre_gor Yeah, but I don't have time to manually include it, and my chip resources are limited so I don't want to import a lot of external libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte HexCharToByte(char c) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        return c - '0';
    } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') {
        return c - 'A' + 10;
    } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') {
        return c - 'a' + 10;
    }
}

void TransformMac(char input[6][2], byte output[6]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        output[i] = (HexCharToByte(input[i][0]) << 4) | HexCharToByte(input[i][1]); 
    }
}
```