# C++ missing inputs (need to print out the values of test1)

Tags: c++, vector

Was hoping to print out the values of test1. I just would like to ask how come the values of test1 are not printed out and only prints out "PRINT START" and "PRINT END". Any help or idea is highly appreciate.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print_out(vector<int> numbers)
{

    cout << "------------- PRINT START -------------" << endl;

    for( auto i: numbers )
        cout << i << endl;

    cout << "------------- PRINT END -------------" << endl;
}

vector<int> beautify(vector<string> numbers)
{

    vector<int> result;
    return result;
}

int main()
{

    vector<string> test1;
    test1.push_back("3167389213");
    test1.push_back("32989741893");
    test1.push_back("2138");

    print_out(beautify(test1));
    return 0;
}
```

#### Update

Thank you, So I've applied the codes inside beautify though it still cant output the test1 values.

```
vector<int> beautify(vector<string> numbers)
{
    vector<int> result;
    for (auto & i : numbers)
        result.push_back(std::stoi(i));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem and where is your question? Also, please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why convert to `int` just to print, why not print directly

Comment: `beautify` returns empty vector which is passed to `print_out` so how can you expect values of `test1` as output.

Comment: Please do not make edits that invalidate existing answers, add updates to your question instead. If you encounter a different problem, please ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is the flow of your program:

- you create an empty vector
- you fill it with strings that contains digits
- you call the `print_out` function with the argument `beautify(test1)` so we need to look what `beautify()` returns.
- `beautify()` returns an empty vector (int)
- `print_out()` prints all elements from the empty vector, so none.

This code is equivalent and maybe clarifies something:

```
int main()
{

    vector<string> test1;
    test1.push_back("3167389213");
    test1.push_back("32989741893");
    test1.push_back("2138");

    vector<int> newVector = beautify(test1);
    print_out(newVector); //here newVector is empty
    return 0;
}
```

What you probably want to do is in your `beautify()` function, convert the string vector to an int vector. See [How do I convert vector of strings into vector of integers in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138960/how-do-i-convert-vector-of-strings-into-vector-of-integers-in-c)

Comment: I thought the values stored in test1 are then passed to the argument

Comment: beautify(vector<string> numbers)

Comment: Hi moffeltje, I tried applying the code though there was an error it says: 49:26: error: could not convert 'test1' from 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >' to 'std::vector<int>'

Comment: @CjMedina use `std::stoi` function to do that

Answer (score 0):

Correct your `beautify` function

```
vector<int> beautify(vector<string> numbers)
{
    vector<int> result;
    for (auto & i : numbers)
        result.push_back(std::stoi(i));
    // If results are to be sorted
    std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}
```

Also, the integers that you push in form of strings are out of range.

```
test1.push_back("3167389213");    // outside the range of int
test1.push_back("32989741893");
```

See http://ideone.com/vOeMHi demo

Comment: @ Shreevardhan May I know what does "for (auto & i : numbers)
        result.push_back(std::stoi(i));" do?

Comment: @CjMedina convert each element of vector to integer and push it in the result vector.

Comment: @CjMedina Yes, the result vector is then passed to `print_out` function. Your code's now working, right ?

Comment: @ Shreevardhan another question if I may, how can I return the result vector values in ascending order?

Comment: @CjMedina add this `std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());`

Comment: yes there was no error though it did not print out the values passed by result I'm not sure if it was passed in printout() for it suppose to print out all the int vectors

Comment: @ Shreevardhan where should I put std::sort(result.begin(), result.end()); exactly?

Comment: @CjMedina it will print once you push integers in range of `int`

Comment: void print_out(vector<int> numbers)
{
    for( auto i: numbers )
        cout << i << endl;
}

vector<int> beautify(vector<string> numbers)
{
    vector<int> result;
    for (auto & i : numbers){
        result.push_back(std::stoi(i));}
        std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}