# Cannot convert from string to hexadecimal

Tags: c++, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ convert hex string to signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer)

I have the string line which is a hexadecimal number say like 12ab43c..(but I have read it as a string)  and I would like to pass it to an unsigned char* linehex or directly to a hexadecimal so I can later use it in my program for further computations. 
Which is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Check out the [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) function.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is probably to read it as a number to start with, instead of reading it as a string, then converting. For example:

```
some_stream >> std::hex >> your_number;
```

Quick demo code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {    
    int x;

    std::cin >> std::hex >> x;

    std::cout << x << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Input: `ff`
Output: `255`