# xor on two hexadeicmal values stored as string in c++

Tags: c++, xor

I have two hexadecimal values which is stored as string:

```
string md5OfPath("a77e0a3e517e0a9d44c3a823d96ca83c");
string guidValue("c3b491e559ac4f6a81e527e971b903ed");
```

I want to perform XOR operation on both the values in C++.
Can you please suggest me on how I can perform the xor operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the straight-forward loop should do the trick:

```
static inline unsigned int value(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') { return c - '0';      }
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') { return c - 'a' + 10; }
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') { return c - 'A' + 10; }
    return -1;
}

std::string str_xor(std::string const & s1, std::string const & s2)
{
    assert(s1.length() == s2.length());

    static char const alphabet[] = "0123456789abcdef";

    std::string result;
    result.reserve(s1.length());

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != s1.length(); ++i)
    { 
        unsigned int v = value(s1[i]) ^ value(s2[i]);

        assert(v < sizeof alphabet);

        result.push_back(alphabet[v]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi,I tried your suggestion, but I am getting some error in the line assert(v < sizeof alphabet); Have I done something wrong. Below is my code

Comment: @sanam_bl: You don't need the asserts. They're just for illustration. You can remove those lines. Otherwise `#include <cassert>`.

Comment: when I print out the value of v , during the third iteration value of v is 4294967284 which is greater than alphabet. and that's why the assert is failing

Comment: Note that there's no guarantee that the code points `'a'` to `'f'` (or `'A'` to `'F'`) are contiguous.  The cleanest and simplest way to convert a single character to a digit is table lookup.

Comment: @sanam_bl: Sorry, had a really stupid error in the conversion function! Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the characters of the strings in parallel and do the `XOR` operation character-by-character, appending characters to a result string as you go through them.

Oh, the `XOR` operator is `^`.

You can have a map for characters to hexadecimal values:

```
`0` -> 0x0
`1` -> 0x1
...
`a` -> 0xa
```

And apply the `^` operator on the values, not the characters themselves.

Comment: Is it possible to perform xor on each individual character? for eg : a ^ c ?

Comment: @sanam_bl it is, but that probably won't give you the result you expect. Note that the character `'a'` isn't the same as the hexadecimal number `0xa`. You'll have to convert it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Split it into shorter strings and follow [this answer for converting hex strings to ints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070499/36537) for each. Then you can XOR or whatever you like on the array of ints you get back.

Splitting into 4 character strings should work; if you use 8 characters you'll hit the 32-bit signed int problem (i.e. negative numbers).

Answer (score 0):

The functional approach to compining two ranges into one in C++ is to use `std::transform`. In  your case, all you need is a function object which performs the xor operation:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct Xor : std::binary_function<T, T, T> {
    T operator() (T a, T b) {
        return a ^ b;
    }
};
```

You can use that to construct a function which xors all characters in two strings:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

static std::string xorStrings( const std::string &s1,
                               const std::string &s2 )
{
    std::assert( s1.size() == s2.size() );

    std::string result;
    result.reserve( s1.size() );

    std::transform( s1.begin(), s1.end(),
                    s2.begin(),
                    std::back_inserter( result ),
                    Xor<std::string::value_type>() );

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants. He probably wants '1' hex_xor 'A' to be 'B' and not 'p' ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The following function (xorTwoHexStrings(string str1, string str2)) can be used

```
#include<sstream>

int hexCharToInt(char a){
    if(a>='0' && a<='9')
        return(a-48);
    else if(a>='A' && a<='Z')
        return(a-55);
    else
        return(a-87);
}

string xorTwoHexStrings(string str1, string str2){
    std::stringstream XORString;
    for(int i=0;i<str2.length();i++){
        XORString << hex << (hexCharToInt(str1[i])^hexCharToInt(str2[i]));
    }
    return XORString.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const char* quads[] = { "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111" };

const char * chrTObin(unsigned char c) {
  if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') return quads[     c - '0'];
  if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') return quads[10 + c - 'A'];
  if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') return quads[10 + c - 'a'];
  return NULL;
  //return -1;
}

char* xorHash(char* chrXOR1, char* chrXOR2) {

    int x;
    int xPos;

    int intXOR1 = strlen(chrXOR1);


    char strBin1[4];
    char strBin2[4];
    char strBin[8];
    char strXORED[4];
    char newXOR[128];

    strcpy(newXOR, "");

    for(x = 0; x < intXOR1; x++) {

        strcpy(strBin, "");
        strcat(strBin, chrTObin(chrXOR1[x]));
        strcat(strBin, chrTObin(chrXOR2[x]));

        strcpy(strXORED, "");

        if(strlen(strBin) == 8) {
            for(xPos = 0; xPos < 4; xPos++) {
                if(strBin[xPos] == strBin[xPos+4]) {
                    strcat(strXORED, "0");
                } else {
                    strcat(strXORED, "1");
                }
            }
        }

        if(strcmp(strXORED, "0000") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "0");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "0001") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "1");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "0010") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "2");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "0011") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "3");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "0100") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "4");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "0101") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "5");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "0110") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "6");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "0111") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "7");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "1000") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "8");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "1001") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "9");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "1010") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "A");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "1011") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "B");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "1100") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "C");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "1101") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "D");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "1110") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "E");
        } else if(strcmp(strXORED, "1111") == 0) {
            strcat(newXOR, "F");
        }

    }

    return newXOR;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if(argc != 3){
        printf("Usage:\n");
        printf("xor HEX1 HEX2\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(strlen(argv[1]) == strlen(argv[2])) {

        char oneXOR[128];
        char twoXOR[128];
        char newXOR[128];

        strcpy(oneXOR, argv[1]);
        strcpy(twoXOR, argv[2]);
        strcpy(newXOR, "");

        printf("XOR: %s %s\n", oneXOR, twoXOR);
        strcpy(newXOR, xorHash(oneXOR, twoXOR));
        printf("RESULT: %s\n", newXOR);

    }

    return 0;
}
```