# C++ Converting color value String to int

Tags: c++, colors, int

I have tried to convert a color code by reading a file, retrieve the color code and store it as a string. This works, but when I tried to just simply convert it to an int, it doesn't work - always getting 0 when I do a cout.

```
string value = "0xFFFFFF";
unsigned int colorValue = atoi(value.c_str());
cout << colorValue << endl;
```

as you can see, the color I've got is 0xFFFFFF, but converting it to an int will only give me 0. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing or what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `atoi` is C not C++ way. Also I believe `atoi` can't handle hex variables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer

Comment: Thanks for the info, What is it that I must do then?

Comment: @Danny Click Daniel's link.

Comment: @DrewDormann sorry, I've posted my comment before I notice Daniel made a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using stringstreams:

```
std::string value = "0xFFFFFF";
unsigned int colorValue;
std::stringstream sstream;
sstream << std::hex << value;
sstream >> colorValue;
cout << colorValue << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @BartekBanachewicz says, `atoi()` is NOT the C++ way of doing this. Leverage the power of C++ streams and use `std::istringstream` to do it for you. See [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/code/217375/converting-a-numerical-value-to-a-string-and-vice-versa).

An excerpt:

```
template <typename DataType>
DataType convertFromString(std::string MyString)
{
    DataType retValue;
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::hex << MyString; // Credit to @elusive :)
    stream >> retValue;
    return retValue;
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but the code as written will still produce the same problem.  `"0xFFFFFF"` will return `0`.

Comment: Yes, just realized that. The solution is trivial, use @elusive's strategy. I'll update my answer :)