# How to convert array of char [HEX] to integer?

Tags: c++

I've array of char [HEX]. I've no idea how to convert them to integer. 
Anyone guide me an idea?

**My Coding:**

```
char Hex[] = {'01', '0D'};

int a = (int(Hex[0]) >> 8)+ int(Hex[1]);
int b = (Hex[0] << 8) | Hex[1];

cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b;
```

**Output:**

```
a: 68 b: 12612
```

I suppose output should be:

```
269
```

Comment: This question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer

Comment: hex is short for hexidecimal or base 16.  So your code should multiply by 16 or shift by 4 if you want hard to read code.

Comment: `char Hex[] = {'01', '0D'};` you need to find out what that means before trying to do more.  It's not what you think it is.  It's the same as `char Hex[] = {'1', 'D'};`

Comment: Just in case it's not clear try `char Hex[] = {0x01, 0x0D};` and you'll get the output you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're completely missing is the ASCII conversion.

`'f'` is a character, with value 0x6f.  Obviously that's not the same as `0x0f`.

Answer (score 0):

your question is very hard to figure out.  I think this is what you want.  Here's how to convert 15 to F and F to 15.  I hope this is what you're asking

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>

int main(){
  // decimal to hex
  std::cout << std::hex << 15 << std::endl;

  // hex to decimal
  int mydecimal;
  std::istringstream("f") >> std::hex >> mydecimal;
  std::cout << std::dec << mydecimal << std::endl;

  // hex to decimal method 2
  std::cout << std::dec << 0xf << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I should probably add that if you want something to become hex.  All you have to do is add that 0x in front of the number