# Hex char array 2 by 2 characters to uint8_t

Tags: c++, c, mbed

I'm making a program for a microcontroller (mbed LPC1768)  and having a few problems to decode serial input to uint8_t.

I get a `char ackBuffer[20];` filled with input from an external device.
What we get is for example: `F040A34B6785121\r`

What I want to do is to get an uint8_t array where each number is symbolized by the hex value of 2 characters. The F is to show the message from the external device is started and the carriage return is the end of each message.

So what I want in the uint8_t array is:

```
0x04
0x0A
0x34
...
```

To make it even harder it can be the ackBuffer is a smaller size, so for example only `F04004A\r` (if this can be easy fixed then it's very nice, but I can work around this problem myself.

Thank you!

Comment: How would you convert the string `"04"` into the integer `0x04`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth An old way of doing that would be `scanf("%2.2x", &val)`.

Comment: ackBuffer[0] = '0'; ackBuffer[16] = 0;/*null terminate*/ Then follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer

Comment: @MadScienceDreams: That's how you would do it on a PC where runtime costs less than development time.  Not on a microcontroller, where processing power is severely limited.

Comment: @Zac: `sscanf` is definitely not a good performance target.  `strtol` would be the best library-provided function, but it is still more general than necessary.

Comment: @BenVoigt True ... I didn't say it was efficient, just that it was old ;)  It was the common method used for hardware communication via serial bus at a company I worked at 12+ years ago.

Comment: Performance is not that much of an issue. The microcontroller runs at 100Mhz and that's fast enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm assuming that an `ackMessage` must start with `'F'` and end with `'\r'`. And I'm even assuming that, since you work on a micro controller, anything that does more than required (eg. library functions) should be avoided. Given that you just have to iterate over the buffer:

```
uint8_t charToHex(unsigned char value)
{
  if (value >= '0' && value <= '9') return value - '0';
  else if (value >= 'A' && value <= 'F') return value - 'A' + 10;
  else if (value >= 'a' && value <= 'f') return value - 'a' + 10;
  assert(false);
}

#define BUFFER_SIZE (20)

int main(void)
{
  char ackBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = "F12345890AB\r";
  uint8_t result[(BUFFER_SIZE-2)/2]; // at most 9 bytes since it's 20 - 2 / 2

  char* ptr = ackBuffer;

  assert(*ptr == 'F');
  ++ptr;

  int count = 0;
  while(*ptr != '\r')
  {
    uint8_t value = charToHex(*ptr) << 4 | charToHex(*(ptr+1));
    result[count++] = value;
    ptr += 2;
  }

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    printf("%x\n", result[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Mind that you must have a `charToHex` consistent with the used encoding and probably you could need some more sanity checks around the code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I was bored :(

Comment: Thanks mate for the fast answer! Will try to do this.

Comment: @BenVoigt: yes, it was a typo (that was correct in the code indeed). Thank you, just fixed it.

Comment: Yes, it ends with a '\r' (carriage return, 13 in ASCII) and not an r. Tried it before with sscanf, but didn't really work out. Also tried some difficult things but also didn't work how I wanted.