# how to make value = strtol (number.c_str(),NULL, number.size()); work?

Tags: c++, iostream

Number is a string == "0x1388" which is 5000 in dec. I'm not sure how to convert this hex string into the int value == 0x1388; Any help? And thanks in advance.

```
    value = strtol (number.c_str(),NULL, number.size());
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer

Answer (score 0):

The third argument is the base of the number you want to convert. In your case, the number is base 16 (hexadecimal), so you should pass `16` as the third argument. You can also pass `0`, which will let the function determine the base from the prefix `0x`.

Answer (score 0):

Fix 3rd argument

```
value = strtol (number.c_str(),NULL, 16);
                                      ^^ Base of hexadecimal number
```

Comment: Would this work for Octal and Dec too?

Comment: @user2904033 Yes, why not ?