# String to hex char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, hex, unsigned

I get a string which is given as an argument to a function like e.g. 00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff and I need to make an unsigned char array of it which looks like this:

```
unsigned char array[16]= {0x00 ,0x11 ,0x22 ,0x33 ,0x44 ,0x55 ,0x66 ,0x77 ,0x88 ,0x99 ,0xaa ,0xbb ,0xcc ,0xdd ,0xee ,0xff};
```

I have no idea how to do it, tried some things with strcpy and thought about hex but this works only with << or >> as I know so I don't think I know how to apply it here. Anyone could help please?

Comment: You want to print all the characters of the string as hex values?

Comment: std::hex might be useful

Comment: @Borgleader Yup, in an array of bytes

Comment: You might get some ideas from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer  The part you need to work out is how to convert 2 digits at a time.

Comment: To the guy who deleted an answer don't worry, it's not my homework, it's just a small problem I had with a bigger program

Answer (score 2):

It seems you need to convert each digit received to a [nibble](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) and to combine two nibbles into a byte. The conversion from digit to nibble can be done using a look-up or using conditional logic for digits and letters. The combination is a bitwise shift and a bitwise or.

I could write the code but I've somewhat outgrown assignments, not to mention that my version is unlikely to be a viable solution anyway.

Comment: "bitwise shit and a bitwuse or." autocowreck or just tired? :P

Comment: @Borgleader: Next time please wait until five minutes have passed before pointing out things like this!

Comment: @Mystical: it seems there is no edit history for the first 5 minutes or so: Borgleader would have needed to wait longer pointing it out...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a combination of istringstream and std::hex.
[example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>


int main() {
    std::string myStr = "1122AA010A";

    std::stringstream ss;
    int n;
    for(int i = 0; i<myStr.length(); ) {
        std::istringstream(myStr.substr(i,2))>>std::hex>>n;
        ss<<(char)n;
        i += 2;
        }

    std::string result = ss.str();

    std::cout<<"\n"<<result<<"\n";
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How do I use std::hex when writing to an array?