# C++ hexdecimal to unsigned char

Tags: c++, decimal

How can I conver hexdecimal string to unsigned char bytes ?

```
std::string = "ffddaabb";
to
unsgined char[] = "\xff\xdd\xaa\xbb";
```

Comment: "\xff\xdd\xaa\xbb" is not an unsigned char

Comment: Start here http://stackoverflow.com/q/1070497/335858, limit to two chars, and add results together as bytes.

Comment: That will be help out.I split them like as you said.And put them one by one and worked .. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is **not** an unsigned char

```
"\xff\xdd\xaa\xbb"
```

The correct type you get by assigning this literal is a `const char` pointer.

In order to get a single char you should do

```
unsigned char ch = 0x2A;
```