# The addition of two hexadecimal numerals in c++

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that takes two hexadecimal numbers and converts them to decimal form, and prints out their sum in decimal form. The maximum length of the numbers is 10. {submit.cs.ucsb.edu/submission/203504}. I feel confuse about the error messages. The problem wants the max length of the numbers is 10. Why the output like "ffffffffff" works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int hexToDecimal(string);
string decimalToHex(int);

int main()
{
    long long hex1, hex2;

std::cout << "Enter first number:" << std::endl;
std::cin >> std::hex >> hex1;

std::cout << "Enter a second number:" << std::endl;
std::cin >> std::hex >> hex2;

if (hex1 >9999999999 || hex2 > 9999999999)

{
    cout << "Addition Overflow" << endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "The sum is "<< std::hex << hex1 + hex2 << "." << std::endl;

}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Number is a number.  Hex or base 10 is just a way to represent it. For me the operation decimalToHex have no sense.  Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer . And finally print it in hex format std::cout << std::hex << decimal << end  and remember. Number are numbers. Hex or decimal is just the way to present it.

Comment: Spend some time testing your code and Googling.

Comment: @Mquinteiro: If I want to set the maximum length of the number is 10, then I use an if statement, but I just get partial credit. Can you help me to take a look for it? submit.cs.ucsb.edu/submission/203493

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to do this:

```
int hex1, hex2;

std::cout << "Enter first hex number:" << std::endl;
std::cin >> std::hex >> hex1;

std::cout << "Enter a second hex number:" << std::endl;
std::cin >> std::hex >> hex2;

std::cout << std::hex << hex1 + hex2 << std::endl;
```

Comment: If I want to set the maximum length of the number is 10, then I use an if statement, but I just get partial credit. Can you help me to take a look for it?  https://submit.cs.ucsb.edu/submission/203493

Comment: In that case, you need to find the length of the number. And this is another question

Comment: Or you can `if (hex1 > 9999999999 || hex2 > 9999999999) { /* length > 10, do something*/ }`, since you only care about length 10.

Comment: I try to use hex1=1, hex2=aaaaaaaaaaa; the expect output is additional overflow, but the output I get is 80000000.

Comment: Okay, try to change `int hex1, hex2;` to `long long hex1, hex2;`

Comment: {https://submit.cs.ucsb.edu/submission/203504}. I feel confuse about the error messages. The problem wants the max length of the numbers is 10. Why the output like "ffffffffff" works?