# Convert Hexadecimal string to decimal number in C++

Tags: c++, string, hex, decimal

I want to convert a hexadecimal string to a decimal number (integer) in C++ and tried with following ways:

```
std::wstringstream SS;
SS << std::dec << stol(L"0xBAD") << endl;
```

But it returned `0` instead `2989`.

```
std::wstringstream SS;
SS << std::dec << reinterpret_cast<LONG>(L"0xBAD") << endl;
```

But it returned `-425771592` instead `2989`.

But, when I use it like below, it works fine and gives `2989` as expect.

```
std::wstringstream SS;
SS << std::dec << 0xBAD << endl;
```

But I want to input a string and get `2989` as output, instead integer input like `0xBAD`. For example, I want to input `"0xBAD"` and cast it to integer and then convert to a decimal number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the question?  You have a working way.

Comment: @NathanOliver I updated it correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer

Comment: [Third parameter `base`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Comment: @ViktorChvátal Yes, I also seems you're correct.

Comment: Why do you think `stol(L"0xBAD")` should work? Did you get a compiler warning on that line?

Comment: @n.m. no, I didn't get any compiler warnings.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is a correct line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// stol example
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::stol

int main ()
{
  std::string str_dec = "1987520";
  std::string str_hex = "2f04e009";
  std::string str_bin = "-11101001100100111010";
  std::string str_auto = "0x7fffff";

  std::string::size_type sz;   // alias of size_t

  long li_dec = std::stol (str_dec,&sz);
  long li_hex = std::stol (str_hex,nullptr,16);
  long li_bin = std::stol (str_bin,nullptr,2);
  long li_auto = std::stol (str_auto,nullptr,0);

  std::cout << str_dec << ": " << li_dec << '\n';
  std::cout << str_hex << ": " << li_hex << '\n';
  std::cout << str_bin << ": " << li_bin << '\n';
  std::cout << str_auto << ": " << li_auto << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! It worked! :-) I googled many times about this and found nothing, because of the way I searched. But, I was unable to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer) post.

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.