# C++ convert string of bytes to ints from file

Tags: c++

I'm completely new to C++, so I guess this might be a very trivial question.  If this is a duplicate of an already answered question (I bet it is...), please point me to that answer!

I have a file with the following cut from `hexdump myfile -n 4`:

```
00000000  02 00 04 00 ...    |....|
00000004
```

My problem/confusion comes when trying to read these values and convert them to ints ( [0200]_hex --> [512]_dec and [0400]_hex --> [1024]_dec).

A minimum working example based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070499):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(void){
    char fn[] = "myfile";
    ifstream file;
    file.open(fn, ios::in | ios::binary);

    string fbuff = "  ";
    file.read((char *)&fbuff[0], 2);
    cout << "fbuff: " << fbuff << endl;

    // works
    string a = "0x0200";
    cout << "a: " << a  << endl;
    cout << "stoi(a): " << stoi(a, nullptr, 16) << endl;

    // doesn't work
    string b = "\x02\x00";
    cout << "b: " << b << endl;
    cout << "stoi(b): " << stoi(b, nullptr, 16) << endl;

    // doesn't work
    cout << "stoi(fbuff): " << stoi(fbuff, nullptr, 16) << endl;

    file.close();
    return(0);
}
```

What I cant get my head around is the difference between `a` and `b`; the former defined with `0x` (which works perfect) and the latter defined with `\x` and breaks stoi. My guess is that whats being read from the file is in the `\x`-format, based on the output when running the code within sublime-text3 (below), and every example I've seen only deals with for example `0x0200`-formatted inputs

```
// Output from sublime, which just runs g++ file.cpp && ./file.cpp
fbuff: <0x02> <0x00>
a: 0x0200
stoi(a): 512
b: 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
[Finished in 0.8s with exit code -6]
```

Is there a simple way to read two, or more, bytes, group them and convert into a proper short/int/long?

Comment: note that `02 00 04 00` is not `0x200` and `0x0400` (if interpreted as 16bit), but `0x0002` and `0x0004` and (if 32bit) not `0x02000400`  but `0x00040002`

Comment: Thanks, so you mean it automatically takes care of endianess?  I also noted there was a typo in  my definition of `b`.  It should have been `string b = "\x02\x00"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The literal string `"0x0200"` is really an array of *seven* bytes:

```
0x30 0x78 0x30 0x32 0x30 0x30 0x00
```

The first six are [ASCII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) encoded characters for `'0'`, `'x'`, `'0'`, `'2'`, `'0'` and `'0'`. The last is the null-terminator that all strings have.

The literal string `"\x00\x02"` is really an array of three bytes:

```
0x00 0x02 0x00
```

That is not really what is normally called a "string", but rather just a collection of bytes. And it's nothing that can be parsed as a string by [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). And as [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) can't parse it the function will throw an exception.

You might want to [get a couple of good books to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and learn more about strings.

---

Note: This answer assumes ASCII encoding and 8-bit bytes, which is by far the most common.

Comment: Great! Thank you for clearing that out and for the book-list.  Two follow-up questions to help my understanding: 1) so what is really read from the file will be in the second form, i.e. just the two bytes `\x02` and `\x00` without null-terminator (but that already sits "outside" of my 2byte-sized string anyway)?   2) I need to write my own function to translate such a hex-string to int, or is there a built-in function for that similar to std::stoi?  A bonus is if it can handle endianess as well, similar to pythons `struct.unpack`-functions.

Comment: And one more question: When I run `a.length()`, I get 6 as you described.  However when running `b.length()` I get 0, but I would expect 2...?

Comment: @user10668188 For the last question its easy to answer: The null-terminator is the character `'\0'`, which is the octal equivalent of `'\x00'`. That is, the string you use to initialize `b` is terminated at the first character, i.e. it's a string of length `0`.