# C++: Convert CONTENT of String to char

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, char

I have a vector which contains strings:

```
vector<string> vectorStr = { "0x6c", "0x9f", "0x71", ... };
```

How do i convert the CONTENT of the strings to chars?. Preferable to a char-array, which in the end looks like:

```
char charArray[] = { 0x6c, 0x9f, 0x71, ... };
```

Seems like i am the first human in history of computer science who has to solve this problem. Everyone else just wants to convert a string into a char-Array, **which is not what i want**.

Comment: Just use an [stoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function with a radix of 16. You might need to remove the hex prefix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ convert hex string to signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer)

Comment: "_Seems like i am the first human in history of computer science who has to solve this problem_" :-) One shouldn't laugh at desperation, but that _was_ funny.

Comment: thanks, your answered helped me to solve this problem. Wish i could upvote :/

Comment: You can update the accepted answer in the linked duplicate if you believe it is a good solution to the problem stated in that question.