# C4302 reinterpret_cast truncation from const _Elem * to unsigned char

Tags: c++

Hi got this message which I need help with:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Warning   C4302   'reinterpret_cast': truncation from 'const _Elem *' to 'unsigned char' row 94

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Warning   C4302   'reinterpret_cast': truncation from 'const _Elem *' to 'unsigned char' row 95

```
    uint16_t Id = 325;
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << std::hex << Id; //Result: 0145
std::string str1 = stream.str().substr(0, 2); //Result: 01
std::string str2 = stream.str().substr(2, 2); //Result: 45
unsigned char char1 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char>(("0x" + str1).c_str()); //Wanted result: 0x01
unsigned char char2 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char>(("0x" + str1).c_str()); //Wanted result: 0x45
unsigned char Mac[6] = { 0x00, 0x1D, 0xE2, 0x03, char1, char2 };
```

Comment: You need to cast to `char*`. `char` is one character, for example 'a' whereas `char *` is a pointer to a character array which hopefully ends with `\0`.

Comment: You need a function `unsigned char parse_hex(std::const std::string&)` instead of casting...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ convert hex string to signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer)

Comment: `unsigned char char1 = ((str1[0] - '0') << 4) + (str1[1] - '0');`?

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the *very* long way round: going from a number to a string, chopping that up, then re-parsing the string as a number...

Instead use simple bitwise operations:

```
unsigned char MSB = Id >> 8;
unsigned char LSB = Id & 0xFF;
unsigned char Mac[6] = { 0x00, 0x1D, 0xE2, 0x03, MSB, LSB };
```