# boost::lexical_cast can convert hex inside string to int?

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast

I see in this topic [C++ convert hex string to signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer) that `boost::lexical_cast` can convert hexadecimal inside string to another type (int, long...)

but when I tried this code:

```
std::string s = "0x3e8";

try {
    auto i = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;        // 1000
}
catch (boost::bad_lexical_cast& e) {
    // bad input - handle exception
    std::cout << "bad" << std::endl;
}
```

It ends with a bad lexical cast exception !

boost doesn't support this kind of cast from string hex to int ?

Comment: Try `std::string s = "0x3e8";`

Comment: @AlanBirtles same issue

Comment: fwiw, if you post a [mcve] it is much easier for others to reproduce the issue. https://godbolt.org/z/da1YMaKnP. Tbh I wonder why it is so common to remove includes and stuff that needs to be added back by others to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the answer from [C++ convert hex string to signed integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070497/c-convert-hex-string-to-signed-integer):

> It appears that since `lexical_cast<>` is defined to have stream conversion semantics. Sadly, streams don't understand the "0x" notation. So both the `boost::lexical_cast` and my hand rolled one don't deal well with hex strings.

Also, as per `boost::lexical_cast<>` documentation

> The `lexical_cast` function template offers a convenient and consistent form for supporting common conversions to and from arbitrary types when they are represented as text. The simplification it offers is in expression-level convenience for such conversions. **For more involved conversions, such as where precision or formatting need tighter control than is offered by the default behavior of `lexical_cast`, the conventional `std::stringstream` approach is recommended.**

So for more involved conversion, `std::stringstream` is recommended.

If you have access to C++11 compiler, you can use `std::stoi` to convert any hexadecimal sting to an integer value.

`stoi` prototype is:

```cpp
int stoi( const std::string& str, std::size_t* pos = nullptr, int base = 10 );
```

Your program can be converted to

```cpp
int main() {
    std::string s = "3e8";
    auto i = std::stoi(s, nullptr, 16);
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

And the output will be

```
1000
```

Comment: It happens the same with `std::from_chars`. A hex parsing of string `0x3e8` will be parsed as `0`, since `0x` is not parsed. A hex parsing of string `3e8` will be parsed correctly. Shame! :(

Answer (score 1):

What you want exists in [Boost Convert](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/convert/doc/html/boost_convert/introduction.html):

> Boost.Convert builds on the boost::lexical_cast experience and takes
> those type conversion/transformation-related ideas further
>
> - to be applicable to a wider range of conversion-related deployment scenarios,
> - to provide a more flexible, configurable and extendible type-conversion framework,
> - to provide generic consistent behavior,
> - to unify and to uniformly deploy various conversion facilities through one consistent interface.

### Simple Usage

You can e.g. use stream conversion:

```
boost::cnv::cstream converter;
```

You can configure it with the manipulators you want, e.g.:

```
converter(std::hex)(std::skipws);  // IO manipulators
```

You could use directly:

```
boost::optional<int> i;
converter(s, i);
std::cout << i << std::endl; // 1000
```

But I'd suggest applying with pre-configured error-handling:

```
auto f = apply<int>(std::ref(converter))
     .value_or(-1); // decorate error-handling
```

Now you can simply write:

```
for (auto s : cases)
    std::cout << f(s) << std::endl;
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c45bcfd4e78d750)**

```
#include <boost/convert.hpp>
#include <boost/convert/stream.hpp>
#include <iostream>

static const std::string cases[]{
    "0x3e8", "3e8", "-7a", "-0x7a",
    "0x-7a", // error
};

int main() {
    boost::cnv::cstream converter;
    converter(std::hex)(std::skipws);                      // IO manipulators
    auto f = apply<int>(std::ref(converter)).value_or(-1); // decorate error-handling

    for (auto s : cases)
        std::cout << std::quoted(s) << " -> " << f(s) << std::endl;

    auto g = apply<int>(std::ref(converter)); // throwing
    for (auto s : cases)
        try {
            std::cout << std::quoted(s) << " -> " << g(s) << std::endl;
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
}
```

Prints

```
"0x3e8" -> 1000
"3e8" -> 1000
"-7a" -> -122
"-0x7a" -> -122
"0x-7a" -> -1
"0x3e8" -> 1000
"3e8" -> 1000
"-7a" -> -122
"-0x7a" -> -122
"0x-7a" -> Attempted to access the value of an uninitialized optional object.
```